# Can not upload Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, router, upload

I can not upload any file from my PC (not as mail attachments, dropbox uploads, etc...)

Everything was good a few days ago, but now I can't upload anything (because of this also pages load slow). I do not recall installing any new programs.

I have tried disabling Firewall, NOD32 antivirus, resetting the router, etc...

**Router**: TP-LINK TL-WR1043ND

**Speedtest**.net says:

- Download Speed: 88.50 Mbps
- Upload Speed: Connecting

**IpConfig**:

```
C:\Windows\System32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : XCS-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 8C-89-A5-CB-8D-D2
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::6983:c08a:759a:b7db%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, January 20, 2014 12:33:48 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, January 20, 2014 2:45:45 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 244091301
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-FF-51-F2-8C-89-A5-CB-8D-D2

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet
1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1133:9183:faf9:b5b%15(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.11.91(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 352342102
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-FF-51-F2-8C-89-A5-CB-8D-D2

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet
8
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b063:dda9:ca29:2417%16(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.36.23(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 369119318
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-FF-51-F2-8C-89-A5-CB-8D-D2

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{D4C79831-6F8D-4CF0-8EBA-30BB94D51135}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{E2B4EF0E-B998-4BB5-AB17-E6D53D48F99F}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{EA842E4C-16A6-48B3-8282-4FF85114A862}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: This is rather odd, since you need to upload *something* to be able to download stuff

Comment: I know, I even managed to "upload" this post :). I have waited for more than one hour to upload a 2MB archive on Dropbox and it's stuck on "uploading". Also, on Facebook chat messages are often not sent, giving an error that the message failed to be sent.

Comment: Since some stuff works and other dosen't, I'd peek at netstat or some other tool that checks connection statuses. Is this problem localised to one PC or can you replicate it with another one?

Comment: Ok, I really need help with this. For example when I Pause/Resume dropbox syncing it starts with 30kb/s and then drops top 5-6kb/s then completely stops ... When it worked (prior to last weekend) the upload speed was about 1MB/s.

Comment: If I `ping dropbox.com -t -l 1024` I get about 45% packet loss. Is this normal?

Comment: 45% packet loss is definitely not normal. Does that occur with all sites or just some (FB and DropBox, evidently, at least)?

Comment: Superuser - 23%, Wikipedia.org 18%, Yahoo.com 28%. The most annoying thing is not that I can't upload files, but web pages load very slow because of this...

Comment: It could be an ISP related issue, unless other computers/devices in the same network are not affected. Packet loss aside, what's the average ping for e.g. `google.com`?

Comment: No, you're clearly having issues. What happens when you bypass the router?

Comment: @and31415 Let the ping for a longer time (300 packets): 25%loss, 191ms average. On the tablet (Wi-Fi connected to the router) everything seems normal.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek By bypassing the router you mean connecting the cable directly to the PC?

Comment: yup. I'd also try switching the cable just to rule that out too

Comment: Ok. On Tablet Wi-Fi Speedtest works, but only says 0.28Mbps. On netbook Wi-Fi or wired SpeedTest upload does not work. Tried to connect the netbook directly via cable and an Eror 651 popped up while connecting to the Broadband connection. So, I put the cable back in the rooter and now everything seems ok ... http://www.speedtest.net/result/3245622150.png :| Hope it stays like this. Might be the cable not making perfect contact? But I disconnected/connected the cable sever times before and it didn't work.